# Rails 4 + Jquery : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some code that works great in Rails 3 but not in Rails 4.

Gemfile:

```
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Assets:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery.ui.mouse
//= require jquery.ui.position
//= require jquery.ui.sortable
```

JS (called):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  url: '/admin/wines/update_regions_and_classifications/' + id,
  timeout: 2000,
  beforeSend : function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json") },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error) { alert("Failed to submit : "+ errorTextStatus+" ;"+error); },
  success: function(data)
  {
    // regions title
    $("<option value=''>" + data["region_title"] + "</option>").appendTo("select#wine_region_id");
    // regions data
    $.each(data["regions"], function(i,j) {
      row = "<option value=\"" + j.region.id + "\">" + j.region.name + "</option>";
      $(row).appendTo("select#wine_region_id");
    });
  }
});
```

Rails controller:

```
  def update_regions_and_classifications
    region_title = "#{t(:Region)}..."
    appellation_title = "#{t(:Appellation)}..."
    if !params[:id].blank?
      @regions = Region.where("country_id = ? AND status=1", params[:id]).order(:name)
      region_title = "#{t(:NoRegion)}" if @regions.empty? 
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => { "region_title" => region_title, "regions" => @regions } }     
    end
  end
```

The @regions array seems to be full.

The error I have when I select a country to fill regions list in a HTML `<select>`:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

But, the JSON is sent to the Ajax callback I'm sure.
Does Rails regions array can be different ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think `j` is the region so try `j.id` instead of `j.region.id `

Comment: Hello Arun,
You are right !!! Thanks.
Can you explain me why this code works in Rails 3.0 but not in Rails 4 ? Something changes in the rails array or in a new version of Jquery ?

Comment: sorry... not worked on rails...